# Regex Command to remove function from all files

Tags: regex, function, notepad++

I am trying to remove the following function from all my working files, while leaving the first argument intact. The second argument changes every time.

```
dotranslate( "Arg1", "Arg2" )
```

I am trying to do this using Notepad++, but I just can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Is the second one at least always a literal string? Or is the call always the only thing on its line?

Comment: The second argument is always a string, as is the first.

Comment: And you want to do that for one specific `Arg1`, or for any two possible string, putting the first string back where the function was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your strings can contain escaped quotes, this will be quite difficult. If not, you can go with this:

```
Find what: dotranslate\(\s*("[^"]*")\s*,\s*"[^"]*"\s*\)
Replace with: $1
```

So this will match `dotranslate(`, then optional spaces, then capture a string. The string is written as `"[^"]*"`. So quotes, as many non-quotes as possible and quotes again. And then we just match spaces, comma, spaces, string, spaces, closing parenthesis.

And replace that with what we captured in the first (and only) set of unescaped parentheses. Which is the first string.

If `Args1` should not be variable, simply write the specific value into the capturing group.

Comment: This is almost perfect thanks. Notepad++ however required me to use \1 instead of $1. You have saved me hours of doing it manually.

Comment: @AshleyStaggs try upgrading to Notepad++ 6. They changed a lot about the regex engine and fixed a few bugs.

Comment: @AshleyStaggs: You may want to investigate learning a scripting language like Perl that makes these sorts of transformations very simple from the command line.